# Get a dynamic variable from this

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dynamic, this

I have searched high and low and can not find a answer specif to the problem. I have a Ajax function that gets data and inserts it into my lisboxes. I could just do a function for each but wanted to cut down on code as I very well might need to do request for other listboxes. The code is as follows:

```
    function getSelectListAjax(getController, getAction, selectToAppendId, idColName, txtColName) {
    var JPath = '../' + getAction;
    $.getJSON(JPath, function (result) {
        var val = idColName;
        var txt = txtColName;
        var ddl = $('#' + selectToAppendId);
        ddl.empty();
        $(result).each(function () {
            ddl.append(
                $('<option/>', {
                    value: this.QuestionId,
                    text: this.Question
                }).html(this.Nome)
            );
        });
    });
};
```

Where it appends to **value:** and **text:** I wanted the variable being taken out of **this.** to be dynamic. So it could be **this.QuestionId** or **this.SectionId** etc.

If someone could please help or send me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript `this.QuestionId` is similar to accessing it via `this['QuestionId']`.

So to dynamically access it with the `val` and `txt` variables use `this[val]` and `this[txt]`.

For more details, read up on dot notation versus bracket notation: ["Working with Objects."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)